# How do I sort text labels to be displayed in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

How do I select what country names the map display? It seems so obvious, however, I can't figure it out. I've used

```
"CNTRY_NAME" = "Denmark" AND "Sweden" AND "Norway"
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Rule-based labeling` and add a specific filter. For example, to label three countries I would use `"CNTRY_NAME"  IS  'Chile'  OR  "CNTRY_NAME"  IS  'Brazil'   OR  "CNTRY_NAME"  IS 'Argentina'` as filter:

[image]

The result is only three countries labeled:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Very similar to the answer by aldo_tapia (upvoted).

I would use the Rule-based labelling, in the same way, but use the expression

`"CNTRY_NAME"  IN ('Chile', 'Brazil', 'Argentina')` - if only to save on typing and making it easier to keep track of the values you wish to display. Also easier to copy and paste in your values from a spreadsheet, or list, if there are many.

[image]

Comment: Yes, great option

Comment: Great!!  (I´m adding 8 countries so this solution works even better!) Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, glad it was useful. The way this site works is to accept the answer and up vote. It then takes the question off of the unanswered list